# Call method with object NSTimeInterval fails

Tags: ios, objective-c, methods, selector, nstimeinterval

I'm working on an app, in which I would call a method, and pass in parameter an `NSTimeInterval`.
My method is declared like this :

```
-(void)MethodwithTime:(NSTimeInterval)t
{
    NSLog(@"Test, T = %f", t);
    ...
}
```

I call it from a `UIViewController`like this :

```
[myObject performSelector:@selector(MethodwithTime:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:t]];
```

Because I read that `NSTimeInterval` is a double. But the `NSLog` test gives me some zeros... Test, `T = 0.000000`

How could I fix it?

Thanks !

Comment: Why are you using `performSelector:`? Why not just do: `[myObject MethodwithTime:t];` ?

Comment: I've fixed it, and was asking for peform selector method =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSTimeInterval` is not an object (it's a typedef for some floating-point number type, but you could have known that if you had read its documentation). Hence when you are trying to interpret a pointer (which Objective-C objects are represented by) as a floating-point primitive, you'll get unexpected results. How about changing the type of the argument of `MethodwithTime:` to `NSNumber *`?

(Oh, and method names start with a lowercase letter and use camelCaps, so `MethodwithName:` is not idiomatic, `MethodWithName:` isn't good either, `methodWithName:` is.)

Comment: If changing the arguments is the only solution that i have, so i'll do.

Comment: @user2057209 Note that then **obviously** you'll have to change how you log it as well.

Comment: @user2057209 Please google that. You have to make some effort yourself too.

Comment: I did. That's why i said that i've found that. See "Because i read that NSTimeInterval is a double"...

Comment: @user2057209 `NSNumber *foo = @(1.5); NSLog(@"%@", foo);` since it's an object.

Comment: @user2057209: Of course it's not the only solution. But until you explain (per rmaddy's comment) why you are not calling it directly, all the other solutions will kinda be pointless.